# Django pass TemplateView to ModelAdmin.add_view

Tags: python, django, angularjs, django-admin

Base on Django Admin site docs... I can override ModelAdmin.add_view to inject one custom view. My need is to inject a TemplateView to override one model change/add admin page.

This custom view will contains an AngularJS app to manage, inside admin, one complex model of my application.

admin.py

```
class ContractAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        return ContractAdminView.???? (.as_view() doesn't work)

# ContractAdminView is a TemplateView.
```

ps: Is this a good way to add an AngularJS powered form/page inside Django Admin??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as_view()` returns the view function which you should call with the `request` parameter:

```
def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    return ContractAdminView.as_view()(request)
```

To add any custom view to the `ModelAdmin` you should override the [`ModelAdmin.get_urls()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) method.  And to match with the admin layout UI your template can extend the `admin/base_site.html` template:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block title %}My title{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    My content and forms here.

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks @catavaran. Only another small tip. I need to develop an add/change admin page which has a lot of form fields and an angularjs (small application) only to computer the values of some fields and update the values of another fields... or I need to load the values of some FKField only after the user has selected another FKField.
I can develop an entire angularjs / rest api stack (without django form); or I can use Django ModelForm, which I can manually render in template to add ng-model directive to any <input ...>, and keep it sync with angular. In your opinion what's the right approach?

Comment: Sorry, I never used AngularJS so can't suggest anything here.

Comment: Thanks anyway.
Right now I've tried to override 'admin/change_form.html' template with my FormVIew but I get: 
NoReverseMatch at /admin/my_django_app/contract/add/ "Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'app_label': ''}' not found."
The admin docs says "Any view you render that uses the admin templates, or extends the base admin template, should provide the current_app argument to RequestContext or Context"...

Comment: Don't override the `admin/change_form.html` - this template requires a LOT of context vars: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1001  Extend the `admin/base_site.html` instead.